# Angular NgModel Does Not Work At All: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, function, ms-word, angular-forms, angular2-ngmodel

### Angular NgModel Does Not Work At All: `Object(...) is not a function`

Even just having `ngModel` on an input was crushing my runtime. **Did I remember to `import` the `FormsModule`?** Yes. Having `#form="ngForm"` on my `<form>` wasn't a problem. Very frustrating -- wasted so much time.

#### Here's the Error

```
ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at _isAndroid (VM19326 taskpane.js:62091)
    at new DefaultValueAccessor (VM19326 taskpane.js:62144)
    at createClass (VM19326 taskpane.js:55008)
    at createDirectiveInstance (VM19326 taskpane.js:54849)
    at createViewNodes (VM19326 taskpane.js:56307)
    at callViewAction (VM19326 taskpane.js:56741)
    at execComponentViewsAction (VM19326 taskpane.js:56650)
    at createViewNodes (VM19326 taskpane.js:56335)
    at createEmbeddedView (VM19326 taskpane.js:56184)
    at callWithDebugContext (VM19326 taskpane.js:57621)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

After searching high and low, I came across [this issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2309) which pointed me to look at my `package.json`. I didn't see anything related to the issue there, but **what I *did* notice was that I had installed `@angular/forms@10.n.n` when all of my other Angular versions were `^5.2.9`. This is because *I installed the npm package manually* because I'm working on a Microsoft Word "Add-Ins" app -- and the Word CLI / Yeoman *does not install `@angular/forms` for you***. This led to a mismatch, which I'm sure can happen in any environment.

#### TL;DR

package.json

```json
"@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "^10.n.n"
```